# Strange java renames json attribute name

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, gson

I have a class like the following on my Soring boot server side:

```
class Questionnaire {
    private string loaderClass = "";

    public String getClassLoaderName(){return this.loaderClass;}

    public void setClassLoaderName(String val){this.loaderClass = val;}
}
```

I have a rest endpoint that simple returns the above class type to a request from the angular side.

On my angular client side, I retrieve the json version the Questionnaire defined above. This is my expectation:

```
{
  "loaderClass": "someValue"
}
```

This is what I get:

```
{
  "classLoaderName": "someValue"
}
```

Who renamed it? How was it renamed? To fix the issue I simply had to rename the setter and getter to match the attribute name on Java side.

This is strange.

Comment: simply why don't you rename the setter/getter to match the field name?

Comment: Why did you tag spring-boot, Jackson, and Gson? Which of those, if any, are you using? How are you using them? Why do you think this is strange? What do you think the name should be and why? If you already know how to address the issue (and therefore its cause (the getter/setter)), what's the problem?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I have asked the question because I did not know the reason behind the behavior.

Comment: We can only guess without you showing us how your server is implemented.

Comment: _rename the setter and getter to match the attribute name_ seems to indicate you know _the reason behind the behavior_.

Comment: I did mention in my post that I had changed the getter and setter to match the attribute.

Comment: Great, so you understand that the getters/setters are involved. What's next?

Comment: I only wanted to know what was causing this. That's it. The below answer was helpful. I was not even aware of such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Jackson renamed it. Your getter is named `getClassLoaderName` and Jackson's [default property naming strategy](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html) is to get rid of the `get` part and lower camel-case the remainder. If you want to change the name you can annotate the getter with [`@JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) like this:

```
@JsonProperty("loaderClass")
public String getClassLoaderName(){return this.loaderClass;}
```

If you want to change the naming strategy itself you can use the [`@JsonNaming`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonNaming.html) annotation in combination with one of the static `PropertyNamingStrategy` implementations, to change the strategy for the entire model class:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.KebabCaseStrategy.class)
class Questionnaire {
   ...
}
```

Or alternatively configure your `ObjectMapper` like this `objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.KEBAB_CASE)` to change the strategy for all models.

Comment: How do I specify that I prefer Gson over Jackson. Is Jackson the default Json tool with spring boot?

Comment: Yes, Jackson is the default JSON (de)serializer that comes with Spring Boot. You can override it by simply adding Gson to your project dependencies. Spring Boot Auto Configuration will detect Gson on the classpath and configure it with sensible defaults.